# passing argument of outer function as argument for inner function in python?

Tags: python

i want to use multiple functions via one outer function. the argument is a string and upon that string i want to create/pass arguments for inner functions. how is that possible?

```
def outer_function(arg1):
    
    arg2 = 'random_text' + str(arg1)
    arg3 = 'random_text' + str(arg1)
    
    def inner_function(arg2,arg3):
        global var
        do_something ...
    return inner_function()
```

my error i get is :

```
TypeError: inner_function() missing 2 required positional arguments:
```

Comment: `inner_function(arg2, arg3)`? The argument names of your inner_function as written _shadow_ the names of those variables in your outer_function. Which means they get overwritten inside the inner_function by whatever arguments are passed when you call inner_function.

Comment: Just turn `def inner_function(arg2,arg3):` To `def inner_function():`
But seriously, what the point of doing so?

Comment: You don't have to pass the outer function variables as parameters to the inner function to use them from inner function, these variables are called closures, look them up.

Comment: Well, How about passing the needed arguments? `return inner_function(arg2, arg3)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't passed arguments or parameters in `return inner_funtion()`below code can help

```
def outer_function(arg1):
    arg2 = 'random_text' + str(arg1)
    arg3 = 'random_text' + str(arg1)
    def inner_function(arg2,arg3):
        global var
        do_something ...
    return inner_function(arg2,arg3)
```

Comment: thank you this on helped. but after the first inner_function is executed it will stop and not execute the second. is there something i will have to add oder command?

Comment: i use multiple inner functions and they all have arg2 and arg3 as arguments#

Comment: Can you elaborate

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `global`, and don't specify the variables as arguments if you're not passing them as arguments.  Functions automatically have access to values from the enclosing scope.

```
def outer_function(arg1):
    arg2 = 'random_text' + str(arg1)
    arg3 = 'random_text' + str(arg1)

    def inner_function():
        return arg2 + arg3

    return inner_function()
```

```
>>> outer_function(" foo ")
'random_text foo random_text foo '
```

Comment: Yes this is the right way to do it. I am surprised to see people skip over the topic of closure which is one of the easiest topics to learn in programming.